# Calculating an expression for the trace of generators of two Lie algebra

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gauge-theory, lie-algebra

Suppose we have 
$$[Q^a,Q^b]=if^c_{ab}Q^c$$
where Q's are generators of a Lie algebra associated  a SU(N) group. So Q's are traceless. Also we have
$$[P^a,P^b]=0$$
where P's are generators of a Lie algebra associated to an Abelian group. We have the following relation between these generators
$$[Q^a,P^b]=if^c_{ab}P^c$$

I would like to know what we can say about the following trace. Is it equal to zero?
$$tr([Q^a,P^b]Q^c P^d)$$

Cheers!

Comment: From the cyclic property of trace we have $$tr[A,B]=0$$ for any matrices. Also $$tr([A,B]C)=0$$ just for symmetric matrices. Maybe these relation help!

Comment: I dont believe this, which rascal has close flagged this? It is a perfectly legitimate technical theoretical questin. **Leave open**

Comment: @Dilaton I flagged it for migration to math.SE . It is a (legitimate) math question.

Comment: the question is  definitely of interest to a lot of people here and lie algebras are used extensively in physics. this question is definitely not out of place in this forum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $P^{a}$ are finite-dimensional matrices, then I found that your algebra
actually implies that $P^{a}=0$. I think that it is a consequence of the fact
that $SU\left(  N\right)  $ is a simple group, i.e., there is no a normal
subgroup in $SU(N)$. If we assume that $P^{a}$ are hermitian then your
identities:
$$
\left[  P^{a},P^{b}\right]  =0,\qquad\left[  Q^{a},P^{b}\right]
=if^{abc}P^{c},\qquad\qquad(1)
$$
are the algebra of an invariant subgroup.

The formal proof that $P^{a}=0$ is as follows. If $P$ satisfies the algebra (1) then a linear independent subset of $P$ also satisfies Eq.(1), therefore without loss of
generality we can assume that all $P^{a}$ are linear independent. Let me now
split $P$ into the hermitian and anti-hermitian parts:
$$
P=\frac{P+P^{\dagger}}{2}+i\frac{P-P^{\dagger}}{2i}=R+iI,
$$
where $R$ and $I$ are hermitian matrices. Taking into account that all
$f^{abc}$ are real and
$$
\left[  Q^{a},P^{b}\right]  =if^{abc}P^{c}\quad\Longrightarrow\qquad\left[
Q^{a},P^{\dagger b}\right]  =if^{abc}P^{\dagger c},
$$
one can conclude that:
$$
\left[  Q^{a},R^{b}\right]  =if^{abc}R^{c},\qquad\left[  Q^{a},I^{b}\right]
=if^{abc}I^{c}.
$$
Therefore $R^{a}$ and $I^{a}$ are hermitian traceless matrices thus they can be
expressed as linear combinations of $Q$. Thus, we find that matrices
$P^{a}$ are  linear combinations of $Q$:
$$
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad P^{a}=M^{ab}Q^{b},\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (2)
$$
where $M^{ab}$ is some $\left(  N^{2}-1\right)  \times\left(  N^{2}-1\right)
$ compex-valued matrix. Again from Eq.(1) we obtain:
$$
M^{ad}\left[  Q^{d},P^{b}\right]  =\left[  P^{a},P^{b}\right]  =iM^{ad}%
f^{dbc}P^{c}=0.
$$
Since all $P^{e}$ are linear independent then $M^{ad}f^{dbc}=0$, thus
$0=M^{ad^{\prime}}f^{d^{\prime}bc}f^{dbc}=C_{A}M^{ad}=0$, hence $P^{a}=0.$

There is another way to show the same. Let's consider the commutator $\left[  Q^{a},P^{b}\right]$ and use the relation (2):
$$
\left[  Q^{a},P^{b}\right]  =M^{bc}\left[  Q^{a},Q^{c}\right]  =M^{bc}
if^{ace}Q^{e}=if^{abc}P^{c}=if^{abc}M^{ce}Q^{e}
$$
Comparing the coefficient of $Q^{e}$, we find:
$$
M^{bc}f^{ace}=f^{abc}M^{ce}\quad\Longrightarrow\qquad M^{bc}\left(
C^{a}\right)  _{ce}=\left(  C^{a}\right)  _{bc}M^{ce}\quad\Longrightarrow
\qquad\left[  M,C^{a}\right]  =0,
$$
where $\left(  C^{a}\right)  _{ce}=-if^{ace}$ are the generators of
irreducible adjoined representation. Therefore, according to Schur's lemma $M$
is a scalar matrix, i.e., $M^{ab}=\lambda\delta^{ab}$. If one requires that
$P$ should be commutative then $\lambda=0.$

The question is what about the case where $P^{a}$ are not finite-dimensional
matrices. But in this case I don't know how to define the trace.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I would like to ask more about your proof. How did you say that $$
\left[  Q^{a},R^{b}\right]  =if^{abc}R^{c},\qquad\left[  Q^{a},I^{b}\right]
=if^{abc}I^{c}.
$$ imply that R and I are traceless? Generally it's strange! Really there is no a non-trivial matrix P that satisfy my relations?

Comment: Probably you know that $\left(  C^{a}\right)  _{bc}=-if^{abc}$ are the generators of adjoined representation. Since for finite matrices
the trace of commutator vanishes, thus $\mathrm{tr}\left[  Q^{a},R^{b}\right]  =0=if^{abc}\mathrm{tr}R^{c}=-\left(  C^{c}\right)_{ab}\mathrm{tr}R^{c}$ implies a linear relation for $\hat{C}^{a}$ which is only possible for all $\mathrm{tr}R^{c}=0$. You can also use the identity $f^{acd}f^{acd^{\prime}}=C_{A}\delta^{dd^{\prime}}$, hence $R^{c}=-iC_{A}
^{-1}f^{abc}\left[  Q^{a},R^{b}\right]  $.

Comment: Based on your proof,  there is no meaningful physical theory with the above algebra.  In fact I am reading  a paper written by R.  Jackiw  http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9705028. If you take a look at page 21 he introduced such algebra for his model.  I would like to know your opinion about it.

Comment: I added alternative way to show the same.

Comment: It is difficult to comment Jackiw's paper without reading it carefully. You question was about the trace thus my proof is valid only for finite matrices. As I noticed it is a consequence of that fact that $SU(N)$, algebraically, is a simple Lie group, i.e., its Lie algebra is simple. Thus if you require that the set of matrices $R^{a}$ has as many components as $Q^{a}$, then it immediately follows that $R^{a}\equiv Q^{a}$.

Comment: But you should keep in mind that it is only about finite matrices. For example, the components of the angular momentum $J^{i}$ are generators for $SU(2)$, and the commutator relation for any "vector" operator $V^{j}$ is $[J^{i},V^{j}]=i\epsilon^{ijk}V^{k}$. Hence if you put $V^{j}=p^{j}$, i.e., the operator of momentum, so that $[p^{i},p^{j}]=\delta^{i,j}$, then you find $[J^{i},p^{j}]=i\epsilon^{ijk}p^{k}$, i.e. the algebra you asked for. But you should remember that translations are not compact (group) thus you cannot define the notion of "trace" for them.

Comment: Generally, you can include $SU(N)$ as a subgroup in some noncompact group $G$, and then you can find an Abelian noncompact subgroup of $G$, so that $SU(N)$ would be a normalizer for this subgroup https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centralizer_and_normalizer Probably Jackiw kept something like this in his mind.

Comment: After one year I am reading your answers again. You are really genius! How do you know such many things about group and algebra theory?!

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is yes if the representation of your abelian group is irreducible, because the generators of an abelian group are *numbers* if I remember correctly.

Actually, a system of "operator" forming a group, and which every element commute with all the other element of the group are numbers *or* proportional to the identity matrix (this is know as the Schuch's lemma if -- once again -- I remember correctly). But if they are proportional to the identity matrix, it means I can easily reduce the representation. At the end I should end up with $U(1)$, which is the only abelian Lie group I know, and this one has a number as generator (an angle say).

So in short, your expression becomes 
$$\text{Tr}\left\{ \left[Q^{a},P^{b}\right]Q^{c}P^{d}\right\} =\mathbf{i}f_{ab}^{e}P^{e}\text{Tr}\left\{ Q^{c}\right\} P^{d}=0$$
**if** the generator of your abelian group are numbers. I used the commutator relation between $P$ and $Q$, I get out of the trace all the numbers (or what I believe are numbers), and I finally used the fact that the $Q$ are traceless.

I prefer to keep the *if* style since I may well make a mistake, but you may easily check by examples. If you find a counter example, I would be glad to learn about that.